# Why do we normalize only the X data and not Y

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normalization

I saw places saying that when using a NN you should **SOMETIMES** normalize your data: we take the `X_train`, subtract the mean and divide by the std.

Is the following statements correct, and if so, why?

- We only normalize the `X` data, and the `y` data stays as is.

Note: The similar Question associated with my post does not answer my question, it talks about why we normalize `X`, but not about the normalization of `y` and the reasons for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree. It may not make much difference if the values are small, but target variable directly affects the gradient size and can result in wild updates during back-propagation. Also, the behavior under regularization may dramatically change. It'll be harder to increase the weights to compensate for the increase in target variable.

On the other hand, note that not all problems demand for mean/std standardization. The target variable might be a probability, and the output activation might be a sigmoid. The above paragraph is intended for general unconstrained regression problems.

Comment: Hi! This doesn't really answer my question. I'm asking about the cases when we do use normalization: do we normalize y values and why?

Comment: @ArielYael You should especially standardize/normalize $y$ values if their scale is large, because otherwise they're likely to cause numerical problems in back-propagation because gradients will probably be large, and typical learning rates won't work well with that scale. It's even more harmful if you use regularization because the target variable's scale will require large weights present in the formula. However, the regularization mechanisms will tolerate large weights up to a certain extent.